# Problems running grass.mapcalc

Tags: python, grass-gis

I am using the GRASS Python Scripting Library on Ubuntu 14.04 with the packages available from the Universe repository. I have the following block of code:

```
        try:
            grass.mapcalc("$weightLine = $seg_rast * $cost",
                        weightLine = "weightLine",
                        seg_rast = "seg_rast",
                        cost = "cost")
        except:
            self.logger.debug("Exception running mapcalc: " + 
                              str(sys.exc_info()))

        kwargs = {}
        kwargs['stdout'] = grass.PIPE
        kwargs['stderr'] = grass.PIPE
        ps = grass.start_command("r.sum", rast="weightLine", **kwargs)
        mesg = ps.communicate()
        self.logger.info("r.sum: %s", str(mesg))
```

Which is logging the following:

```
[2014-06-03 09:57:35,532] DEBUG: Exception running mapcalc: (<type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>, SystemExit(1,), <traceback object at 0x7ffcbab1de18>)
[2014-06-03 09:57:35,538] INFO: r.sum: ('', 'ERROR: Raster map <weightLine> not found\n')
```

The employment of `sys.exit()` is not very helpful, even though it can be worked around. Without the `except:` block it exits my script and any other processes that may have invoked it. Note also that `except Exception, e:` does not catch `exceptions.SystemExit`.

But worst of all, the `mapcalc` instruction is not succeeding. It is either failing - in which case an error message is lacking - or it is simply not being executed.

How can I know the cause of this?

**Update I**: I have tried to run `grass.mapcalc` in different ways:

```
grass.mapcalc("weightLine = seg_rast * cost")
```

And:

```
weightLine = "weightLine"
seg_rast = "seg_rast"
cost = "cost"            
grass.mapcalc("%s = %s * %s" % (weightLine, seg_rast, cost))
```

But the result is always the same: `exceptions.SystemExit` and the command is not executed.

Comment: You need to use %s in the mapcalc function (it is Python, not shell). See e.g. this randomly selected example: http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/trunk/scripts/i.pansharpen/i.pansharpen.py#L159

Comment: Hi Markus, if I try with `grass.mapcalc("weightLine = seg_rast * cost")` I get the exact same result: the `SystemExit` exception and no map calculated.

Comment: I think what Markus meant is something like:  `grass.mapcalc('%s = %s * %s" % (weightLine, seg_rast, cost))`

Comment: Hi Micha, I already tried this too. I do not think this problem is related to string formatting, in that case I would probably be receiving a different exception or an error message.

Comment: I guess you have already confirmed that the command directly in GRASS works as expected?

Comment: Yes Micha: `> r.mapcalc expression=weightLine=seg_rast*cost
 100%`  `> r.sum weightLine
Reading weightLine...
 100%
SUM = 6447.000000
`

Comment: Your script is lacking on top: import grass.script as grass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a working grass.mapcalc() example based on your map names:

```
import grass.script as grass

weightLine = "weightLine"
seg_rast = "seg_rast"
cost = "cost"
grass.mapcalc("%s = %s * %s" % (weightLine, seg_rast, cost))
```

In case of errors, check if the input maps are existing.

Comment: Hi again Markus. I do not get any error messages up to the `r.sun` command. The question is, if any of datasets is missing, shouldn't I be receiving an error message instead of `exceptions.SystemExit`?

Comment: Prior to the `mapcalc` command the `seg` dataset is being imported with: `grass.read_command("v.in.ogr", flags="o", output="seg", input="seg.gml")`. I find out this command is failing, but I am getting no exception, nor any error message. I would expect: a) `v.in.org` to return an error message in case it fails; b) `mapcalc` not invoking `sys.exit()` but rather to return an error message too.

Comment: Hi, you need to check the return code of every process you run (in case of `*_command` functions). I actually think that the GRASS API should be improved to support what you are asking for (http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/2326). `mapcalc` function exits because it is consistent with the behavior of GRASS C library. However, you can change this behavior by calling `grass.script.core.set_raise_on_error(True)` at the beginning of your script then `ScriptError` will be raised.